# Update macro to use sheet data when setting formula

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I have a query formula that I'm using to extract data from different spreadsheets. In the spreadsheet I'm working in, I have tabs for different months: July, August, September, etc.

On each tab, I have this query formula (with a different URL for each month):

```
=query(importrange("**https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/month**","A:G"), "select * where Col7 = 'X'")
```

I tried recording a macro to update the 'Col7= 'X', however, when I use it in the other tabs, it also automatically changes the URL to that of the month it was when I recorded the macro.

How can I get the macro to change the only X and not the URL?

Comment: No code & no spreadsheet example data means we can't know what to recommend gets changed

Answer (score 0):

any reason why not use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> (?). you can do it like this:

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you! This works, however, I'm moreso wondering if it's possible to automate this through code.